# Python code editor for Android

Tags: android, python

I'm looking for an Android app that supports Python code editing with

- Syntax highlighting and code completion
- Supports undo/redo feature, built-in virtual keys for tags and popular keyphrases.
- Has built-in Help
- Interpreter(Optional)

Like Sublime Editor for Windows

The app (or the service provided by a website) should be preferably free, even though I could also accept/evaluate paid options.

Answer (score 0):

These may be what you are looking for:

1. [Pydroid 3](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.iiec.pydroid3&hl=en_US&gl=US)
2. [QPython 3L](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.qpython.qpy3&hl=en_US&gl=US)

QPython doesn't work with every library. On the other hand, in Pydroid 3 you have to pay if you want to install some libraries. Both of them support syntax highlighting, but not code completion. Also, both of them have interpreters and terminals.